# ASP.Net intellisense incorrectly suggesting webroot for paths

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

Following a Pluralsight course I'm coding an ASP.NET 5/MVC 6 web app from effectively scratch. When referencing an object in the format such as:

```
~/js/site.js
```

or

```
~/css/site.css
```

in an .cshtml file, Intellisense is showing an error, saying the files can't be found suggesting the paths should be instead:

```
~/wwwroot/js/site.js
~/wwwroot/css/site.css
```

However *using the first group of paths* references the files correctly on the actual webpage, but *using the second group of paths, as Visual Studio suggests* breaks the webpage and both the js and css aren't loaded.

The items are located under the wwwroot folder, as you can see here:

[image: Solution Explorer]

Why is Intellisense behaving this way, and how can I fix this behavior?

**Edit:** Here's the project.json file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final"
    },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you running the latest release (i.e. RC1) of MVC6?

Comment: 6.0.0-rc1-final. Included the project.json so the versions of the dependencies can be viewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your intellisense to reference your files under the wwwroot without error, your project.json file needs to have the following:

"webroot": "wwwroot",

That should resolve your issue. This minor issue is a known bug at MS when you create a new MVC project with scaffolding in Visual Studio 2015. I think it has been resolved with 6.0.0-rc 1-final.